# System.Linq.Enumerable.Join - result is larger than input set

Tags: c#, linq

I have a System.Linq.Enumerable.Join command like this

```
            var k = ... (List of size 50)
            var r = ... (another List of size 20000)

            var joined = k.Join(r,
                x => x.joinId,
                y => y.somecomplexmember.joinId,
                (first, second) => new ResultInternal { k = first, r= second });
```

As I understood http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx , this should perform an inner join. The result should then be smaller or equal than the minimum of the length of k or r. However, the size of "joined" is larger than 50.

Did I understand something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have 1, 1, 1 and 1, 1, 1 then the first item will match three in the second sequence and the second item will match three in the second sequence and the third item will match three in the second sequence giving you ... 9 results.

Comment: Yes, but joinId in "r" should be unique (not in k)...

Comment: Examining the the results should shed light on the situation. You should be able to figure out which items are "duplicates"

Answer (score 1):

you can always perform it like simple where clause if your are looking for inner join and only matching ids in a query expression

```
var joined=(from x in k from y in r where x.x.joinId==y.somecomplexmember.joinId  select new
  ResultInternal { k = x, r= y});
```

inner join in query expression

```
var joined=(from x in k
join y in r on  x.x.joinId equals y.somecomplexmember.joinId
select new  ResultInternal { k = x, r= y});
```